# Edited - some PDFs generated are corrupt - using ColdFusion

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

Edit - There are some customer accounts that are reporting a $0 balance due on their online accounts but there is an actual balance due.  It is with these accounts only that the PDFs will not open.  Data import issue at this point?

I have a set of CF functions in which new PDFs are generated from database records and available on user accounts for download or viewing.  The code has worked great up until a couple weeks ago, but now the new or old (previous monthly bills) PDFs will not open (corrupt) on the user account pages.  The record data has not been changed or modified.  Could this be CF update issue or what could have caused files to now generate corrupt?  Any help is appreciated.

PDF Analysis of the corrupt PDF files gives:

PDF Errors:

Open file.
0x80410108 - E - The end-of-file marker was not found.
    - File: 11118749.pdf
0x8041010A - E - The 'startxref' keyword or the xref position was not found.
    - File: 11118749.pdf
0x80410108 - E - The end-of-file marker was not found.
    - File: 11118749.pdf
Close file.

CF PDF Generation Code:

```
<cfcomponent>

<!---***************************************************************************--->
<cffunction name="getBill" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="billID" required="yes" default="">
    <cfquery name="getPayment" datasource="#application.dsnName#"       username="****" password="****">
    SELECT * FROM ccos_cust_bill 
    WHERE billID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" maxlength="20" value="#arguments.billID#">
    </cfquery>        
    <cfreturn getPayment>
</cffunction>
<!---***************************************************************************--->


<!---***************************************************************************--->
<cffunction name="getCustBills" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="accountNum" required="yes" default="">
    <cfquery name="getCustBills" datasource="#application.dsnName#" username="****" password="****">
    SELECT * FROM ccos_cust_bill
    WHERE accountNum = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" maxlength="20" value="#arguments.accountNum#">
    ORDER BY billDate DESC, billID DESC
    </cfquery>        
    <cfreturn getCustBills>
</cffunction>
<!---***************************************************************************--->


<!---***************************************************************************--->
<cffunction name="addBill" access="public" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="formvalues" required="yes" default="">
    <cfquery name="addBill" datasource="#application.dsnName#" username="****" password="****">
    INSERT INTO ccos_cust_bill (billID, accountNum, billDate, dueDate, billTotal)
    VALUES (
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" maxlength="20" value="#arguments.formvalues.billID#">, 
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" maxlength="20" value="#arguments.formvalues.accountNum#">, 
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" maxlength="20" value="#DateFormat(arguments.formvalues.billDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")#">, 
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" maxlength="20" value="#DateFormat(arguments.formvalues.dueDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")#">, 
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" scale="2" maxlength="20" value="#arguments.formvalues.billTotal#">
    )
    </cfquery>
    <cfset addOK = "Y">
    <cfreturn addOK>
</cffunction>
<!---***************************************************************************--->


<!---***************************************************************************--->
<cffunction name="getBillPDF" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="billID" required="yes" default="">
    <cfargument name="accountNum" required="yes" default="">
    <cfquery name="getPayment" datasource="#application.billsDsnName#" username="****" password="****">
    SELECT * FROM ccos_bills 
    WHERE billID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" maxlength="20" value="#arguments.billID#">
        AND accountNum = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" maxlength="20" value="#arguments.accountNum#">
    </cfquery>        
    <cfreturn getPayment>
</cffunction>
<!---***************************************************************************--->

<!---***************************************************************************--->
<cffunction name="getNextDueDate" access="public" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="accountNum" required="yes" default="">
    <cfquery name="getNextDueDate" datasource="#application.dsnName#" username="****" password="****" maxrows="1">
    SELECT dueDate FROM ccos_cust_bill
    WHERE accountNum = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" maxlength="20" value="#arguments.accountNum#">
        AND dueDate >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" maxlength="20" value="#DateFormat(now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")#">
    ORDER BY dueDate
    </cfquery>        
    <cfreturn getNextDueDate.dueDate>
</cffunction>
<!---***************************************************************************--->

</cfcomponent>
```

CF View PDF Code:

```
<cfparam name="URL.billID" default="">
<cfset getBillPDF =    application.billCFC.getBillPDF('#URL.billID#','#session.accountNum#')>
<cfif getBillPDF.RecordCount GT 0>
<cfoutput query="getBillPDF">
    <cfset fileData = "#BinaryDecode(billData, "Base64")#">
    <cfheader name="content-disposition" value="inline; filename=#billID#.pdf" />
    <cfcontent type="application/pdf" variable="#fileData#" />
</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
You are not authorized to view this bill.
</cfif>
```

PDF Import into Database

```
<!--- CCOS Bill PDF Data --->
<cfquery name="deleteData" datasource="#application.billsDsnName#"  username="#application.billsDsnUser#" password="#application.billsDsnPass#">
DELETE FROM ccos_bills WHERE billDate < '#DateFormat(DateAdd("d", -180, now()), "yyyy-mm-dd")#'
</cfquery>
<!--- Check to see how many files Exist --->
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#ExpandPath('.')#\files" name="filelist">
<cfset fileCount = 0>
<cfoutput query="filelist">
    <cfif name CONTAINS "ccos_cust_bill_pdf"><cfset fileCount = fileCount + 1></cfif>
</cfoutput>
<!--- Loop over the files and Load the new data --->
<cfloop from="1" to="#fileCount#" index="i">
    <cfquery name="insertData" datasource="#application.billsDsnName#" username="#application.billsDsnUser#" password="#application.billsDsnPass#">
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '#Replace(ExpandPath('.'), "\", "\\", "ALL")#\\files\\ccos_cust_bill_pdf#i#.txt' IGNORE
    INTO TABLE `ccos_bills`
    FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    TERMINATED BY '|'
    <!---IGNORE 1 LINES--->
    (`accountNum`, `billID`, `billDate`, `billData`);
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
<cfquery name="fixbillDate" datasource="#application.billsDsnName#" username="#application.billsDsnUser#" password="#application.billsDsnPass#">
UPDATE ccos_bills SET dateCreated = '#DateFormat(now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")#' WHERE dateCreated IS NULL
</cfquery>
<!---***********************************************************************************--->
```

Comment: Two points.  First, where does the variable billData come from?  Two, if getBillPDF has more than one row, what should happen and what do you think does happen?

Comment: Hi Dan, billData is a column in the ccos_bills table as seen in the getBillPDF function.  If there is more than one row the else statement should appear I believe.

Comment: Your guess as to what happens with more than one query row is not how I interpret the code in your question.  That may or may not be relevant.  In any event, does the problem occur every time?  If not, start looking at the data for when the problem occurs.

Comment: The problem occurs every time.  So even if a user clicks on an older monthly PDF statement it will not open.

Comment: What happens if you use `<cfdocument>` instead of `<cfheader> and <cfcontent>`?

Comment: it just goes to a 500 internal server error if I change either of those or both

Comment: Code recommendations; either use the local scope or use "var" to declare your cffunction variables.  Example in getBill(), the query should be named; local.getPayment in the cfquery and cfreturn tags.  This keeps those variables from becoming global variables and can save many hours of painful debugging.

Comment: Do you have example code for how the PDF files are getting stored in the ccos_bills.billData column?  Perhaps the PDF's are corrupted on the way into the database.

Comment: I am thinking the same thing Scott.  I just added that import section, it is the last section of code on this question now.

Comment: If I can just narrow the issue down at least

Comment: *LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE* How does that import a binary PDF?